# How to Add Fonts to the Shopify Admin

Tags: shopify

I need to add custom fonts to the Shopify panel.

[image]

I added the code in base.css, but they didn't show up in the panel. How can i do this?

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Lexend", sans-serif;
  src: url('{{ "Lexend-Light.woff2" | asset_url }}') format("woff2"),
    url('{{ "Lexend-Light.woff" | asset_url }}') format("woff"),
    url('{{ "Lexend-Light.ttf" | asset_url }}') format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Lexend", sans-serif;
  src: url('{{ "Lexend-SemiBold.woff2" | asset_url }}') format("woff2"),
    url('{{ "Lexend-SemiBold.woff" | asset_url }}') format("woff"),
    url('{{ "Lexend-SemiBold.ttf" | asset_url }}') format("truetype");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually add fonts there, those are coming from shopify's cdn. You can however find fonts on google fonts or buy a paid font. If you buy a paid one you need to upload the fonts under the assets folder and then you have to import them into the stylesheet much like you already did.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I downloaded the fonts from Google Fonts. Please write in more detail how I should connect them?
That is, in the admin panel, I will not be able to change them, right?

Comment: You can't actually add them to the admin panel as that comes from the shopify cdn.

Comment: I used to add them to assets but from memory that no longer works best to put it in admin -> content -> files and get the cdn uri from there

Comment: Can I create a base font_picker place my own font_picker with my custom font?

Comment: No that is a shopify limitation